# TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of null

Tags: mongodb

here is my code :

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb')
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient

const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/edx-course-db'

MongoClient.connect(url, (err, db) => {
    console.log('Kudos. Connected successfully to server')
    db.close()
})
```

error :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of null
>       at MongoClient.connect (/home/akshay/nodeJs/node-edx/mongoDB/mongodb-script-project/server.js:11:6)
>       at args.push (/home/akshay/nodeJs/node-edx/mongoDB/mongodb-script-project/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:404:25)
>       at /home/akshay/nodeJs/node-edx/mongoDB/mongodb-script-project/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:270:21
>       at connectCallback (/home/akshay/nodeJs/node-edx/mongoDB/mongodb-script-project/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:935:5)
>       at /home/akshay/nodeJs/node-edx/mongoDB/mongodb-script-project/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:784:11
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

Answer (score 0):

You aren't ever checking the `err` object to see if it successfully connected. That callback will be invoked whether the connection is successful or not. Callbacks are simply invoked when the function completes its call, it does not imply success or failure of the call.

Check the `err` object for more details, but I suspect the `mongod` is not running on that port.

Try running the following commands to verify the `mongod` is running.

```
netstat -tulpn | grep mongod
mongo --eval "db.version()"
```

Comment: sorry this answer not help me, I were find this answer. I were not start mongod service so my code show this error.

Comment: "I were not start mongod service so my code show this error"

This is what I said in my answer, that the `mongod` was not running on that port. Apologies for not being clear but this means it is either on a different port or not running at all. The `netstat` command would tell you if the `mongod` is listening on a port.

However it is still important to note that your code does _not_ check that the `db` object is non-null and the `err` object is also not checked to ensure the connection was successful.